# Algolia search by category in swift

Tags: swift, algolia

I have a "records" indices structured in Algolia like this

`[{
    "date": "2018-01-04T13:00:00.000Z",
    "title": "Record 1",
    "status": "new",
}, {
    "date": "2018-01-04T14:00:00.000Z",
    "title": "Record 2"
    "status": "accepted",
}]`

Using swift, I'm trying to just get the objects with a "new" status but have had no luck. According to the documentation, this should be all I need.

```
let apiClient = Client(appID: "XXX", apiKey:"XXX")
let index = apiClient.index(withName: "records")
let query = Query()
query.filters = "status:new"
index.search(query) { (content, error) in
    print("RESULTS", content, error?.localizedDescription)
}
```

I've also tried

```
    query.filters = "status:\"new\""
```

I can't even get a query like this working in Algolia's dashboard GUI. Do you need to "enable" this kind of query somewhere in the Dashboard?

If I disable the filters I get all the records (as expected) but filtering returns no results and no errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a facet on your attribute `status`? 
The syntax `query.filters = "status:new"` only works with facets.

See here for more exemples: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/faceting/#faceting-overview

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have some minor issues in your JSON (some extra `,`), see the correct form:

```
[{
    "date": "2018-01-04T13:00:00.000Z",
    "title": "Record 1",
    "status": "new" 
}, 
{
    "date": "2018-01-04T14:00:00.000Z",
    "title": "Record 2",
    "status": "accepted" 
}]
```

If the objects are properly imported, what you need in order to use the filters is to set them up using `attributesForFaceting`. This should be a one time operation that you can do it from your backend or in swift.

If you want to do it in swift, here's a [link](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-swift/blob/48bc6f17b6555d8966dc4d95d6c87d22cd576857/Tests/IndexTests.swift#L916) that shows how to do it.

Basically, you only need one time to set the settings:

```
let customFilter = ["status"]
let settings = ["attributesForFaceting": customFilter]
index.setSettings(settings)
```

Reload the page and now you should see on the left size a menu with the title `status` and the possible values.

[image]